# Allowing threads from python after calling a blocking i/o code in a python extension generated using SWIG

Tags: python, swig, rtsp-client

I have written a python extension wrapping an existing C++ library [live555](http://live555.com) (wrapping RTSP client interface to be specific) in SWIG. The extension works when it is operated in a single thread, but as soon as I call the event loop function of the library, python interpreter never gets the control back. So if I create a scheduled task using `threading.Timer` right before calling the event loop, that task never gets executed once event loop starts. To fix this issue, I added `Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS` and `Py_END_ALLOW_THREADS` macros manually in the SWIG auto generated wrapper cxx file around every `doEventLoop()` function call. But now, I want to do the same (i.e. allow threads) when SWIG generates the code itself and not to change any code manually. Has anyone done something similar in SWIG?

P.S. - I would also consider switching to any other framework (like SIP) to get this working. I selected SWIG over any other technology is because writing SWIG interface was really very easy and I just had to include the existing header files.

Comment: If you use ctypes to call into a C DLL, it will release the GIL automatically.  Did you look into using ctypes?

Comment: @FogleBird I thought ctypes only works for C library, not C++. I will investigate more into that.

Comment: Oh yeah, C++ is trickier and I haven't dealt with it in ctypes.  Sorry I don't have a better answer for you.

Comment: Seems like SIP has annotations that will release/acquire GIL: http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/sip4/using.html#the-python-global-interpreter-lock

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SWIG gives you plenty of hooks to help make this happen.  If a coarse solution is sufficient for your needs, one thing I've done in the past is put something like this in my .swig file:

```
%exception {
    Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS
    $action
    Py_END_ALLOW_THREADS
}
```

This (ab)uses the SWIG facility for decorating C function calls with some kind of error-handling logic in order to decorate those calls with a GIL unlock/lock.  See [Exception handling with %exception](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Python.html#Python_nn44) in the SWIG docs for details on what's going on here.